# Why is wi-fi not working with terminal downloading?

Tags: wireless, command-line, proxy

I usually use internet in my college where we have to use college proxies for downloading. As a result , I had updated my apt.conf file to include the information for the college proxies so that I could download and update using terminal . 
But now at home , when I tried downloading using broadband connection from terminal , it is always trying to connect to the college proxy even though I have removed the info from the apt.conf file. Downloading from software center is Ok but through terminal ,its always trying to connect to the college proxy.

Comment: In the dash search for **network** open it and select Network proxy.  You should be able to remove the proxy from there.  You will need to re-enable the proxy when you go back to university,

Comment: I already did this but same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Probably u need to go to a browser and change the HTTP proxy to no proxy.
In google chrome, go to settings-> Change Proxy Settings -> Network Proxy
here delete the info and apply it system wide.

Hope this helps ...:)